# Using fetch inside the for loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm beginner to a JavaScript. I developed one code to fetch some URLs output using fetch API. When I used below code it says, *Functions declared within the loop is referencing an outer scoped variable*.
I understand that it is due to outer scope of obj variable but how can I make it work.
Kindly help. Below is the code,

```
var obj = [
  {"Id":"10101","descr":"server1.com"},
  {"Id":"10102","descr":"server2.com"},
  {"Id":"10103","descr":"server3.com"},
  {"Id":"10104","descr":"server4.com"},
  {"Id":"10105","descr":"server5.com"},
  {"Id":"10106","descr":"server6.com"}, 
  {"Id":"10107","descr":"server7.com"}
];

var temp = [];
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){      
  
  var id = obj[i].Id;      
  fetch('https://abced.com/api/'+id+'/value', {
    method : "GET",
    headers: { "Authorization": "xyz" }
  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => { 
      var stats = data.status;          
      if (stats != "OK") {
        temp.push({ Id: obj[i].Id, descr: obj[i].descr, value:"ERROR" });
      }
      console.log(temp);
    })
    .catch(x => console.log("fail:", x))

}
```

My expected output is. *(values of Id and descr will depends on if statement in the code)*

```
[{"Id": "10101","descr": "server1.com","status": "ERROR"},
{"Id": "10103","descr": "server3.com","status": "ERROR"},
{"Id": "10104","descr": "server4.com","status": "ERROR"}]
```

Comment: Your code has quite a few basic syntax errors, unfortunately. Can you fix those please and edit your question accordingly?

Comment: [The closure explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example).

Comment: And please indent your code to improve the readability.

Comment: You should work with async: https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-fetch-async-await/

Comment: You may also want to read up on asynchronous events in javascript in general: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-the-event-loop-callbacks-promises-and-async-await-in-javascript

Comment: push the fetch promise which resolves the value to an array of promises, then use Promise.all to do something once they have all resolved https://playcode.io/1078971 don't go down the async/await route else the for loop will be blocking

Comment: The message is probably not referring to `obj` and `tmp`, but more likely to `i` and `id`. Both `i` and `id` are defined within the for-loop using `var`. This means there is one single `i` and `id` variable that is shared between the different iterations. By the time the `.then()` callbacks are called, `i` is no longer the same but instead is `obj.length`. `id` will be set to the last `id` in the loop. As a rule of thumb, always use `let` or `const`. Only use `var` if you have a specific reason for doing so. Defining `i` and `id` with `let` means that each iteration has its own variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using the [`async...await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) syntax, this is a lot easier to read than lots of .then() handlers.

We'd use a [`for .. of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop to iterate through each Id, descr value in our obj array, making the relevant `fetch()` call for each one.

We *await* the result of each fetch call, then test the status. If it's not OK we add to the results array.

```
var obj = [
  {"Id":"10101","descr":"server1.com"},
  {"Id":"10102","descr":"server2.com"},
  {"Id":"10103","descr":"server3.com"},
  {"Id":"10104","descr":"server4.com"},
  {"Id":"10105","descr":"server5.com"},
  {"Id":"10106","descr":"server6.com"}, 
  {"Id":"10107","descr":"server7.com"}
];

async function getResults() {
    const results = [];
    for(let { Id, descr} of obj) {
        const data = await fetch('https://abced.com/api/' + Id + '/value', {
          method : "GET",
          headers: { "Authorization": "xyz" }
        }).then(res => res.json());
        if (data.status !== 'OK') {
            results.push({ Id, descr, value: 'ERROR' })
        }
    }
    return results;
}

async function test() { 
    const results = await getResults();
    console.log('Results:', results)
}

test();
```

Below is a snippet where I've mocked out fetch, this should give you an idea of what to expect.

fetchMock returns a status of 'BAD' for ids 10101, 10103, 10104 and 'OK' for all the others.

```js
// For testing only, replace with fetch when appropriate...
function fetchMock(url) {
    let id = url.split('/')[4];
    if ([10101, 10103, 10104].includes(+id)) {
        return Promise.resolve({ json() { return Promise.resolve({ status: 'BAD'})}})
    } else {
        return Promise.resolve({ json() { return Promise.resolve({ status: 'OK'})}})
    }
}

var obj = [
  {"Id":"10101","descr":"server1.com"},
  {"Id":"10102","descr":"server2.com"},
  {"Id":"10103","descr":"server3.com"},
  {"Id":"10104","descr":"server4.com"},
  {"Id":"10105","descr":"server5.com"},
  {"Id":"10106","descr":"server6.com"}, 
  {"Id":"10107","descr":"server7.com"}
];

async function getResults() {
    const results = [];
    for(let { Id, descr} of obj) {
        const data = await fetchMock('https://abced.com/api/' + Id + '/value', {
          method : "GET",
          headers: { "Authorization": "xyz" }
        }).then(res => res.json());
        if (data.status !== 'OK') {
            results.push({ Id, descr, value: 'ERROR' })
        }
    }
    return results;
}

async function test() { 
    const results = await getResults();
    console.log('Results:', results)
}

test()
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: This seems to be working but it is also returning a promise pending along with array
**Promise {<pending>}**
**(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]**
I have another piece of code which sitting the above code that returns value only, here is that code snippet
`fetch('https://getserver.com/api').then((res) => res.json()).then(function(data) {
    var value = data.values;
    const formatData = (temp) => {
        return temp.map(({
            Id, value: {descr}}) => ({Id, descr})); };
    var output = formatData(value);
    console.log(output)
}).catch(e => {
   console.log("fetch fail: " + e);});`

Comment: It'll return a promise pending if you don't await it in the calling function. You can also  call .then() on the result.

Comment: Is it possible write whole code with ".then" notation because that seems to be working for my system. (Like the snippet I added in previous comment)

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. This issue is sorted.